# Why is this function corrupting the values in my array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

When I include the function called tipAverage, the values for the array "tips" in the Mark object are wrong. However, when I delete the function tipAverage, the values are correct.

I am trying to understand what is happening with the code (i.e. the control flow). Could somebody please tell me why and how the function tipAverage corrupts the values in the aray "tips" in the Mark object? Thank you.

```
var tipJon = {
    fullName: "John Smith",
    billValues: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],

    calcTipJon: function (){
        this.tips = [];
        this.totalBill = [];        

        for (var i = 0; i < this.billValues.length; i++){

        var percentage; 
            var bill = this.billValues[i]
        if (bill < 50){
            percentage = 0.2;
        } else if (bill >= 50 && bill<= 200){
            percentage = 0.15;
        } else if (bill> 200){
            percentage = 0.10;
        }

        this.tips[i] = this.billValues[i] * percentage;
        this.totalBill[i] = (this.billValues[i] * percentage) + this.billValues[i];

        }

    }    
}

var tipMark = {
    fullName: "Mark Miller",
    billValues: [77, 375, 110, 145],

    calcTipMark: function (){
        this.tips = [];
        this.totalBill = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < this.billValues.length; i++){

            var percentage; 
            var bill = this.billValues[i];

            if (bill < 100){
                percentage = 0.2;
            } else if (bill >= 100 && bill<= 300){
                percentage = 0.1;
            } else if (bill > 300){
                percentage = 0.25;
            }

            this.tips[i] = bill * percentage;
            this.totalBill[i] = bill + bill * percentage;
        }
    }
}

tipMark.calcTipMark();
console.log(tipMark);
tipJon.calcTipJon();
console.log(tipJon);


function tipAverage (arrayName){
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayName.length - 1; i++){
        //arrayName[i] = arrayName[i] + arrayName[i];
        arrayName[i] += arrayName[i + 1];
    }

    return arrayName[i] / arrayName.length; 
}

console.log("TIP AVERAGE " + tipAverage(tipMark.tips));
```

Comment: We cannot know what the purpose is of your code. What is "correct" and what is "corrupted"? What is the expected output and how does it differ from what you get?

Comment: Do you not know what `+=` does?

Comment: One thing: on tipAverage you're iterating through the array, until "arrayName.length-1" and yet you're summing "arrayName[i+1]" <- on the last iteration you're out of bounds.

Comment: @MarceloMyara, that's not true.

Comment: Sorry, trincot's right. Presumed the usual "<=". My bad...

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your code calculates an average is wrong. It changes almost every value, but fails to calculate a sum.

You can calculate an average correctly like this:

```
function tipAverage (arrayName){
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++){
        sum += arrayName[i];
    }
    return sum / arrayName.length; 
}
```

Or, a bit more functional:

```
function tipAverage (arrayName){
    return arrayName.reduce((a,b) => a+b, 0)/arrayName.length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

The array is passed as itself (by reference?) to the tipAverage function. Therefore, when you modify entries in the functions array parameter (e.g. `arrayName[i] += arrayName[i + 1]`) then the array itself changes. These changes will be seen outside the tipAverage function.

Your best bet is to pass in a copy of the array using one of a variety of methods:

```
console.log("TIP AVERAGE " + tipAverage(tipMark.tips.slice()));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, the real fix is to use an algorithm that actually adds up the array elements.

Comment: Yes, the algorithm is incorrect as well. I was answering the question as to why the `.tips` array was different (corrupt) coming out of the `tipAverage` function.

Comment: Thanks very much guys. I understand now.